# How to revert org-ctrl-c-tab in Org?

Tags: org-mode, byte-compilation, undo

I accidentaly pressed the keys `C-c C-i` which executed the command org-ctrl-c-tab.

According to the self-documentation:

```
org-ctrl-c-tab is an interactive and byte-compiled function defined in
org.el.gz.

Documentation

Toggle columns width in a table, or show children.
```

I am pissed off because my home file .org file became:

"..."

I can't revert this. I tried the `undo` command. But it does not work.

Why did this happen? Can I revert the changes and get my text back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep calm and call that same function.  If that doesn't do it, simply undo, close the buffer and reopen.

Comment: You saved the day, again! Thanks, herói sem capa! :)

Comment: +1  - particularly the "Keep calm" part :-)